# Unit Testing Error when i use JsonRequired Attribute in Dto Class

Tags: c#, json.net

My unit testing is failed when i change Required field to `JsonRequired`
my Dto Class

class name = customerDto

```
[JsonRequired]
public int ID {get; set;}
[JsonRequired]
public int Name{get; set;}
```

When use Required Attribute it was passed.

My Test Code

```
var data = new customerDto {ID = ValidID};
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
httpContext.Request.Body = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
```

in above line debug will stop. i need to fix this.

My unit testing failed when i use JsonRequired Attribute. But it will successfully debug when i use Required attribute

Answer (score 1):

Your `customerDto` is set to require the `Name` property to be given a value when converting to JSON. Your test converts the `customerDto` to JSON. Your test does not set a value on the `Name` property.

Either modify the test to supply a value to the `Name` property or remove the `JsonRequired` attribute from the `Name` property.

Your test does not do anything that would excercise the `Required` attribute. That's why you did not have problems when using that attribute.